# Show that the point of inflection of the graph of $g(x)=x^3+ax^2+4x+2$ is always on the graph of $h(x)=-2x^3+4x+2$ for all values of $a$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$a \in \mathbb{R}$

How can I even find the inflection point, I tried to solve this problem manually by finding the second derivate but was stucked because I still had an equation with two variables, $x$ and $a$.

Also tried to solve using CAS and again was stucked with $x$ as a function of $a$.

Does someone here know how one can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are right, inflection points come from solving
$$
0 = g''(x) = 6x + 2a \iff x = -a/3.
$$
Now, plug in this point into $g$ to get $g(-a/3)$ and we have to show that $g(-a/3) = h(-a/3)$. Notice that the last 2 terms agree in both functions, so you only have to show that
$$
0 = g(-a/3) - h(-a/3) = (-a/3)^3 + a(-a/3)^2 - 2(-a/3)^3
$$
Note that $a^3/3^2$ readily cancels from both sides to leave
$$
0 = -\frac13 + 1 + \frac23
$$
which is true and completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that only $g(x) = x^3+ax^2+4x+2$ is given, but $h(x)$ is not known in advance. It is straightforward to show that $g(x)$ has a unique inflection point, which depends on the parameter $a$. Then, a natural question would be what is the locus of the inflection point when $a$ varies.

To answer that question, first step is to determine the inflection point, which turns out to be:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= - \frac{1}{3} a
\\ y = g\left(-\frac{a}{3}\right) &= \frac{2}{27} a^3 - \frac{4}{3} a + 2
\end{align}
$$

As expected, the inflection point depends on $a$. The locus of the inflection point can be determined by eliminating $a$ between $x,y$, in this case substituting $a=-3x$ in the second equation:

$$
y = \frac{2}{27} (-3x)^3 - \frac{4}{3} (-3x) + 2 = - 2x^3 + 4 x + 2
$$

This matches $h(x)$ in the problem, of course, only this way did not require knowing it in advance.